# showing TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found ; when converting list to text

Tags: python

Iam trying to solve the babynames problem in google python class and executed the following script.

```
def extract_names(filename):
  year=0
  f=open(filename,'rU')
  contents=f.read()
  match = re.search(r'(/w+/s/w+/s)(/d/d/d/d)',contents)
  if match:
    year=match.group()
  names=[]
  names.append(year)

  names_rank={}
  m = re.findall(r'<td>(/d+)</td><td>(/w+)</td><td>(/w+)  </td>',contents)
  for item in m:
    (r,boyname,girlname)=item
  if boyname not in names_rank:
    names_rank[boyname]=r
  if girlname not in names_rank:
    names_rank[girlname]=r
  sorted_names=sorted(names_rank.keys())
  for name in sorted_names:
    names.append(name+' '+names_rank[name])
  return names
def main():
  args = sys.argv[1:]

  if not args:
    print 'usage: [--summaryfile] file [file ...]'
    sys.exit(1)
  summary = False
  if args[0] == '--summaryfile':
    summary = True
    del args[0]
  for filename in args:
    names = extract_names(filename)
    t = '\n'.join(names)

  if summary:
    fileout = open(filename, 'w')
    fileout.write(t + '\n')
    fileout.close()
  else:
    print text

if __name__ == '__main__':
```

in function main ,it indicates an error

```
File "babynames.py", line 78, in main
t = '\n'.join(names)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

here names is a list and my aim is to  make text out of the whole list by using

```
    t = '\n'.join(names)#where t is the text
```

but it showing int found , what may be the reason for that.how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the first element of `names` is an integer and it should be a string if you want to join them together. Try this:

```
t = '\n'.join(str(n) for n in names)
```